# Sequential input in a list using python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I wrote a code that is based upon some word tricks. There is a predefine word in my code. The code asks for user input. Then it compare between the predefine word and user input. If they are same it will produce an output.

My code:

```
letter_list=[]
words="admit"
i=0
while i< len(words):
  user = input("Letter: ")
  if user in words:
    letter_list.append(user)
    i=i+1
  else:
    i=i+1
if len(words)== len(letter_list):
  print("Same word")
else:
  print(letter_list)
```

Output(if they got same input similar to words):

```
Letter: m
Letter: i
Letter: a
Letter: t
Letter: d
Same word
```

Output (When given letter not similar to words )

```
Letter: r
Letter: t
Letter: m
Letter: a
Letter: k
['t', 'm', 'a']
```

Although the code gave the output `same word` but it can be easily understandable that they are not. I gave the same letters as user input at the time of compilation but they are not in order. But my code says they are same. In the case of second input it only takes similar letter of words. So the number of letter in the list is 3.

I want to know that how could it takes input sequentially?

I mean when I will give `m` or `i` after `a` it will not take `m` or `i` and prompt wrong letter until it will get `d`.

Comment: You're just checking the length. Put the letters into a string and check if the strings are equal.

Comment: You can check `if user = words[i]:`

Comment: Yeah. But I want to take inputs sequentially. a then d then m and so on.

Comment: Yes I can write user = words[i], But i is a counter variable so it increases. Like, first I give input a, then i increase from 0 to 1 and will not get d. Then i incraese again to 2. Now it get d. But i assume it should get m so it will not include d there. So how can I handle this situation?

Comment: See my answer. The counter variable doesn't increase when they get it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the user's letter is the current character in `words`. If not, print "wrong letter" and don't increment `i`, so it will keep waiting for the user to enter the correct letter.

You don't need `letter_list`, since you won't get out of the loop until the user enters all the correct letters.

```
while i < len(words):
    user = input("Letter: ")
    if user == words[i]:
        i=i+1
    else:
        print("Wrong letter")
print("Same word")
```